# Dynamically adding rows to DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, draw

I'm trying to add dynamic a row on https://DataTables.net .
I understand when I set `processing: true` , `serverSide: true` and `ajax`, I can't add new row in the table.

my code `Datatable` is:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    dom: 'Bftip',
    keys: true,
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    pageLength: 5,
    columns: subColumns,
    ajax: {
        url: ...,
        type: get,
    },
    buttons: [
        {
            text: '<i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>',
            action: function () {
                table.row.add({
                    "id": "",
                    "title": "t100",
                    "order": "100",
                    "mimeType": "101",
                    "thumpnailMimeType": "102",
                    "height": "103",
                    "width": "104"
                });
                
                //table.columns.adjust();
                //table.draw();
                
            },
        },
    ]
});
```

[image]

I used `table.columns.adjust();` and `table.draw();`, But they don't work.
I see [how to add rows to DataTable](https://www.datatables.net/examples/api/add_row.html) too. but I think that's working for offline tables. I can see added the row with `table.data()`, but I can't see that in the table.
Thanks

Comment: I see in your action you are saying `subTable.row.add` but you are initialising the DataTable with `var table = $('#example').DataTable`.....
Your code should work if you use `table.row.add` then do `table.draw();` after

Comment: have a look at this fiddle: [Test](https://jsfiddle.net/f0916gpn/) which works.

Answer (score 0):

I think we can't do it because it doesn't have any solution, but I can destroy (`table.destroy();`) the table and create a new `DataTable` without `ajax`, `processing` and `serverSide` attributes. Then call `table.draw()` after add new row.

For example:

```
table.destroy();

table = $("#example").DataTable({
    // same options without ajax, processing and serverSide
});

// TODO add new row

table.draw();
```

Comment: Oh no, don't destroy the table and recreate it. You can manually add the row with `table.row.add({......});  table.draw();`. It is definitely possible, I use this frequently. If it is still not working - do you have any errors in your console?

Answer (score 0):

Before you edited your question... You were using `subTable.row.add` instead of `table.row.add`.

Otherwise your code looks correct (Can't see what your actual columns are called because you are using a variable in the `columns` property) and this should work.

Here is a working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f0916gpn/) example.
You can use this:

```
var table;

table = $('#example').DataTable({
dom: 'Bftip',
keys: true,
//processing: true,
//serverSide: true,
pageLength: 5,
columns: subColumns,
ajax: {
    url: ...,
   // type: get, 
   // ^^ No need for this, method: 'get' is default
},
buttons: [
    {
        text: '<i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>',
        action: function () {
        // You have to use the "table" variable here below
            table.row.add({
                "id": "",
                "title": "t100",
                "order": "100",
                "mimeType": "101",
                "thumpnailMimeType": "102",
                "height": "103",
                "width": "104"
            });
            
            table.draw();
            
        },
    },
]
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot, but your example doen't have ```ajax``` attribute.

Comment: Please see line **10** in the example...

Comment: I mean in ```Fiddle``` hasn't ```url``` attribute. I changed my method in the project.